# 'django-admin' is not recognized however i installed django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, backend

'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i wrote pip install django and it installed. but when I try this: django-admin --version in cmd it wrote this:
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What's the problem??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.